# Modifying the Paper Onboarding framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

I wanted to implement a onboarding sequence for my app, and I ended up using Paper Onboardinghttps://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding.

Im still kinda new to programming and I am trying to do something as simple as removing the bottom slider icons on the last screen as i instead want my own buttons to appear to ask for Location Services permission:

[image]
You can see the page indicator I want to remove under my buttons

The framework has little documentation and the developers are not answering any questions on their github page so I am wondering how to go about this. Preferably in a general way so I can apply this to other frameworks.

I found that i could use the following function to manipulate image, header and text, but not what seems to be called the pageView

```
 func onboardingConfigurationItem(_ item: OnboardingContentViewItem, index: Int) {
        //item.imageView?.alpha = 0
    }
```

The autocomplete just lets me access these three:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to remove the pageIndicator?

What are my options here? Do I have to change the framework? Is this standard procedure to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just setting the color of the page indicators equal to the background color.